# Qt: detect rectangle hover

Tags: qt, geometry, hover

Is there any class in Qt that i can pass (x,y) coordinates to and ask "what known rectangle is hovered"? Rectangles are added to that object at initialization procedure.

Rectangle may be represented by any class that can hold (x1, y1, x2, y2).

Comment: can you please elaborate what you mean by `Rectangle` and to what object you are adding it.

Comment: You can use QRect to represent your rectangles, and it's QRect::contains(const QPoint& point) method will tell you if the point is inside it.  But you might want to tell us why you need this for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

cmannett85 right

```
if QRect(l, t, b, r).contains(QPoint(x, y)):
    print("Point is inside Rectangle")
```